# When trying to build, fabric plist error appears

Tags: ios, swift, plist, google-fabric

I was able to build this project, then after one build attempt, I could not build anymore. I don't know how this broke because it was building normally, then all of a sudden it stopped working. I even checked out to a previous branch with the same error.

[image]

I have already tried deleting the derived data and cleaning/ restarting xcode.

Comment: Did you add script into building phase?

Comment: Yes, the app used to build until it just stoped working.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, I do not remember if this was ever resolved. I have moved away from this project